# TestComplete error for Panda library Import "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, pandas, 32bit-64bit, testcomplete

I am facing this below given error for Pandas library only via Testcomplete. I am able to add path of libraries with given code. Even other library xlrd is also working but issue only coming for Pandas library. As error is mentioning 32bit so only anomaly I see is that OS is 64 bit, TestComplete is also 64 bit but Python which is installed as part of Testcomplete is 32 bit. Whether anything to be changed to Python version of 32 bit or it is code issue;

Note: When i use Python directly on command prompt shell and try to import pandas in that compiler and run basic function of pandas so it is working there. problem seems only when I load pandas in TestComplete.

**Code:**
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 15\Bin\Extensions\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\")
import xlrd

#sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 15\Bin\Extensions\Python\")
#pandas_loc="C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 15\Bin\Extensions\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\"
#sys.path.insert(0,pandas_loc)

import pandas as pd

def main():
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users\user\Downloads\Test1.xls")

**Error**
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

**OS**
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz   3.00 GHz
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 20H2
OS build    19042.1466
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

**TestComplete**
Version: 15.20.341.7 x64

**Python**
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:34:34) [MSC v.1928 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
python           : 3.8.10.final.0
python-bits      : 32
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 10
Version          : 10.0.19042
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 140 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : None
LOCALE           : English_United States.1252

**Panda Library**
Name: pandas
Version: 1.4.1
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: The Pandas Development Team
Author-email: pandas-dev@python.org
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\program files (x86)\smartbear\testcomplete 15\bin\extensions\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by:

**Python Libraries**
Package         Version

---

numpy           1.22.2
pandas          1.4.1
pip             22.0.3
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2021.3
setuptools      56.0.0
six             1.16.0
xlrd            2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a few issues here;

Firstly, your paths should have double-slashes so the path delimiter is properly escaped, e.g. `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\..."`

Secondly, you shouldn't need to explicitly append the TestComplete Python Library path, since that's automatic.

Thirdly, the Library path you're attempting to append is the path for TestComplete's 32bit Python interpreter. The 64bit Python Library is here;

```
<TestComplete>\x64\Bin\Extensions\Python\Python38\Lib
```

Lastly, it may be better to approach imports by referencing Python installed for the system (provided it matches the TestComplete python version, at time of writing with TestComplete v15 this is Python v3.8 ). This way you can use System environment variables, Aliases etc. and use Pip to install packages and dependencies.

If you've co-installed a more recent version of Python, you can create Powershell aliases to your older version by following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/troyfontaine/e1174ffa2140e7d6f092fe0984225a1d). E.g.

```
Set-Alias pip38 "C:\Python38\scripts\pip.exe"
```

Then you need to make sure your required packages are installed;

```
pip38 install pandas
```

In TestComplete's script editor, you can then insert the system Python 3.8 Library path - wherever you installed it - and import whatever package you require;

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'C:\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages')
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

user = Project.Variables.WindowsUser
workbook_file = "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\Downloads\\Test1.xlsx"

def main(): 
  workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(workbook_file)
```

You can find further information on [working with Python](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/specifics/python.html) within TestComplete in the documentation.